# How to detect freely-drawn shape on Inkscape or GIMP?

Tags: gimp, inkscape, shapes

I would like to have the functionality shown in the following video on Inkscape (preferrably) or GIMP: https://youtu.be/rsFaQZAIZZI?t=18s

The user should be able to draw a rough circle, square, rectangle, triangle etc. with a pencil tool and the application should detect its shape and turn it into a crisp shape (vectorized, if possible).

Does this feature exist in either application, either built-in or as a plug-in?

Comment: Can you tell us something more about your efforts? Have you tried to use the [bezier tool](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-path.html) and stroke the path? See also [here](https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Bezier_Selections/).

Comment: Paths can create arbitrary shapes. I would like to create basic ones in a very quick way. That's why I would like to autodetect shapes after drawing with a pencil tool.

My goal is to create a very quick figure-drawing application for drawing pictures for lectures. I tried drawing stuff with a Wacom tablet, but I don't have a steady hand to draw gracefully. My drawings become crooked.Did that clarify?

Comment: Your goal was clear, and as far as I know there isn't a similar tool in GIMP nor in Inkscape. My question was: *what have you tried to do*? Have you performed searches on the net? Have you tried to simplify the path or use a smooth pencil in Inkscape? Have you requested for a new feature in GIMP or Inkscape forums? As reference, you can find your desired function - just for circles and rectangles - in [this editor](http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/editor/svg-editor.html).

Comment: Hm, that editor seems nice! It's a good starting point. I've done some searches, but haven't found anything. I'm considering developing that feature as an Inkscape plugin myself. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

No, Inkscape does not have a tool with the ability to detect the shape of a free-drawn shape and convert it to a vector version of that shape.

There is however, a Wishlist item in the Inkscape bug tracker from 2011 asking for this feature: https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/714745